# How to create Hive table on top orc format data?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hiveql

I have source data in orc format on HDFS.

I created external hive table on the top HDFS data with below command. I am using hive 1.2.1 version.

> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test( table_columns ... ) ROW
>   FORMAT FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001' STORED AS orc LOCATION 'path'
>   TBL PROPERTIES("orc.compress"="SNAPPY");

But while selecting data from table I am getting this exception.

```
"protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message was too large"
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: **1.** For a columnar format such as ORC the `row format` clause is ignored because it makes no sense, just use `stored as` **2.** What did create that ORC file? Which version of the format? Did you try to inspect the file with the Hive command-line utility?

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC#LanguageManualORC-ORCFileDumpUtility